# surprised Rationalize will sometimes leave a Real unchanged

Tags: numerics

I was surprised that Rationalize will sometimes leave a Real unchanged even if the fractional part of the Real is well above zero.

```
a=571628.2812`
b=Rationalize[a]
(* 571628.2812 *)
a===b
(* True *)
```

I had code blow up because of this, because I explicitly wanted to use only Integer and Rational to avoid rounding-error corner cases, but Rationalize allowed a Real to slip through where it was unwelcome.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Rationalize`. It explains why this happens and states that `Rationalize[x, 0]` will rationalize any number.

Comment: Well, my face is red. Thanks for reminding me to read the documentation examples.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to the helpful suggestion from Bob Hanlon to just read the documentation (my face is red) and use the second argument for Rationalize.

```
Rationalize[571628.2812`, 0]
(* 1429070703/2500 *)
Rationalize[(1/3)*1.,0]
(* 1/3 *)
Rationalize[(1/10)*1.,0]
(* 1/10 *)
```

Notice that even using the zero 2nd argument will not prevent Rationalize from returning the proper form of fractions that have no precise binary representation.

Rationalize without the 2nd argument will simply pass if no rational number is close enough.

```
Rationalize[N[Pi]]
(* 3.14159 *)
Rationalize[N[Pi], 0]
(* 245850922/78256779 *)
Rationalize[N[Pi], .01]
(* 22/7 *)
```

As seen above, Rationalize with a zero 2nd argument will always force a rational to be returned, even if the denominator is ugly because it is large. Where readability is desired, use an appropriately sized non-zero 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
myRationalize[x_Integer] := x;
myRationalize[x_Rational] := x;
myRationalize[0.] := 0;
myRationalize[x_Real] := Block[
   {y},
   y = Rationalize@x;
   If[Head@y === Real, y = Round[x*1000000000.]/1000000000];
   y
  ]
```

```
myRationalize[571628.2812`]
(* 1429070703/2500 *)
myRationalize[(1/3)*1.]
(* 1/3 *)
```

The magic number used is one billion, which takes care of my use case of counting wholes and fractions of grams of plastic resin pellets to the (frankly unnecessary) precision used by an MRP inventory system. I would prefer a solution without using a magic number based on knowing the domain of the problem.

I was thinking about using RealDigits manipulation to calculate a number to replace the magic constant...

```
RealDigits[571628.2812`]
(* {{5, 7, 1, 6, 2, 8, 2, 8, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 6} *)
```

...but I was unexcited to strip zeros, take due care of wherever the decimal point may be, etc. Properly careful code will be slow, I guessed.